# Updating UI during AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ui-thread

How can I edit the views of an activity from an AsyncTask BEFORE the task is complete?  I cannot access any of the views from the doInBackground method, and I do not want to wait until the task has completed.  Is there a way to go about doing this?  Or do I have to create a thread within the doInBackground (which sounds to me would be bad practice) and then access the view on that thread's completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this method:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}
```

Call it in `doInBackground()` of your AsyncTask. This method `publishProgress(Progress... values)`

happens on the UI thread when you call it from  `doInBackground()`.

For more information, read [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.  I set up a static variable in my AsyncTask and when I wanted to update the view, I set it to true, which made the doInBackground call publishProgress.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2694189 What's so special in your case that you need static variable?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the lookup time for static variables is faster

Answer (score 1):

You need to override this method inside your AsynTask Class:

```
  @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading); 
                bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }
```

You can define a progress bar as I show in here and set some value into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the class `MyAsyncTask` containing the following:

```
private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    super(context);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.title);
    progressDialog.setButton(
        DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
        context.getResources().getString(R.string.abort), 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    ); 
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params) {
    progressDialog.setMessage(params[0]);
}
```

You can then use the `ProgressDialog` to report back to the GUI, e.g., by calling `publishProgress("TEST")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the UI from `onProgressUpdate()`. There is a tricky way, you can send some integer or boolean value to progress update and change your UI according to the condition.

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            if(values[0] == 1) {
          //    update the UI
                button.settext("updating");
            }
        }
```

You can call onProgressUpdate fram asynctask by calling

```
publishProgress(1);
```

Hope this works, try out.